# ng-pattern change the model to undefined instead of leaving it and not allowing submit

Tags: angularjs

Hey it's my first time with angular,
I wish to have an input with pattern validation,
Soo, I've added this input to my form:

```
<input type="text"
     id="id"
     name="fieldName"
     ng-model="path.to.field"
     ng-pattern="/^[^a-z]*$/gm"  
/>
```

but I have two problems with it:

1. I have two input that listening to the same model, and when you enter invalid value - the model changes to undefined and the second input gets undefined as well.
   and in this case, you will see the invalid value in the first input, and undefined in the second.
   also, you will see error in the first input but not in the second one - because it gets undefined.
2. I want to allow user leave this field empty, but when they enter invalid input, and the model changes to undefined, the submit will pass - even when the input they entered is invalid.
   but they don't know the value was send empty.

Comment: It looks like this question is about AngularJS, but you added the Angular tag, please fix it. Also if you just started with AngularJS, please stop, [it's deprecated](https://blog.angular.io/discontinued-long-term-support-for-angularjs-cc066b82e65a). Use Angular instead: https://angular.io/

Comment: sry It's my first time using angular, fixed it :) 
it's a legacy code I need to maintain in my company